# Struggling with Facebook Connect and Phonegap Build

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I guess the problem is, I'm not sure what I should be putting in the settings, so any help would be greatly appreciated, as when I run the app with all the setting below I get the Facebook screen opening with an error saying :

"Invalid Scope: public_info"

Here's my app code:

**Config.xml:**

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.8.0">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="**IS THIS MY FACEBOOK APP ID?**" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="**HAVE NO IDEA WHAT I PUT HERE?**" />
</gap:plugin>
```

**index.html**

I read somewhere that I need these includes, but I have no idea if this is the case in PhoneGap Build?

```
<script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
<script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>
```

**index.js**

I'm simply trying to log the user in, nothing more:

```
onDeviceReady: function()
{
var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) 
        {
            alert("UserInfo: ");// + JSON.stringify(userData));
        }

        facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_info"], fbLoginSuccess, function (error) { alert("" + error) });
}
```

**Facebook Developer**

This is where I get even more confused, so any help, as I have no idea if these are correct?

Package Name : **ped-test-app-1**

Default Activity Class Name : **ped-test-app-1.MainActivity**

Key Hashes : **I created this using the keytool and openSSL, and it looks to be in the same format, but do I need to compile my app with the signing key each time?**

Sorry there's so much, but like I said, any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all that; it's a simple documentation error:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_info"] has been superseded with:

facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
```